# On the irreducible submodules of adjoint representations $\text{ad}^{0}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, galois-representations

Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$.  Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\rm{GL}_{n}(k)$ of order prime to $p$ where $n\geq2$. Assume that the representation $H\hookrightarrow \rm{GL}_{n}(k)$ is absolutely irreducible. Let $\text{ad}=M_{n}(k)$ with the action of $H$ coming from the adjoint action of $\rm{GL}_{n}(k)$ with the inclusion $H\hookrightarrow \rm{GL}_{n}(k)$. Let $\text{ad}^{0}$ be the matrices of trace zero in $ M_{n}(k)$, and we can view $\text{ad}^{0}$ as a $k[H]$-module. My question is the following:

> For every irreducible $k[H]$-module $A\subset \text{ad}^{0}$, is there
> an element $x\in A$ and a nontrivial element $g\in H$ such that $x$ is
> $g$ invariant? (That is, the action of $H$ on $A$ is not free.)

One can show that the answer to the question is Yes when $n=2$ by checking all possible modules $ A$, cf. Lemma 4.1 in [Böckle, G., 1999. Explicit universal deformations of even Galois representations]. So, what if $n\geq 3$?

Comment: If $n=2$, then $H$ is just a non-abelian subgroup of $GL_2(k)$ of order prime to $p$.